# Kinesis Video stream - Multiple producers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am able to send an RTSP video stream from my machine to Amazon Kinesis Video Stream. I want to know is it possible to send multiple RTSP video stream (Multiple producer) from one edge device?
Currently I followed this docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/examples-gstreamer-plugin.html#examples-gstreamer-plugin-docker. Using this docs I am able to send a stream to Video server. To send another video I have to stop the current video stream only then i can send other streams. Is there anyway I can send multiple Video streams without disturbing other video streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issue with having multiple streams on 1 device, please take a look at this example as it shows this exact use case, https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/blob/master/samples/kvs_gstreamer_multistream_sample.cpp.

If you're trying to have 1 stream which will contain the multiple streams in sequential order, there's another sample that shows how to upload multiple files with 1 stream, the next files get appended to the same stream, https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/blob/master/samples/kvs_gstreamer_sample.cpp#L1103-L1160. In this case, you need to be careful with the timestamp so that they don't overlap.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used the suggested example code. It's working properly for some streams for other streams it's not working. it shows, [DEBUG][2020-07-02 05:48:16] streamReadyHandler invoked
[DEBUG][2020-07-02 05:48:16] Stream is ready: some-base_0
[DEBUG][2020-07-02 05:48:16] appsink configured
[DEBUG][2020-07-02 05:48:16] Pipeline playing
After that it's not uploading content eventhough the stream is happening

Comment: So, which case are you doing? Also, can you see if the problem is within your gstreamer pipeline by piping your source to an autovideosink?

Comment: - When I try to connect Secured RTSP stream, It's not working. Basically authentication part is not working. I tried to send authentication directly to the url as well as user-id and user-pw argument. both are not working.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Lukas Herman reply.. It might be a faster turnaround time to ask these questions (also) directly in the appropriate GitHub repository: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/issues

Comment: I have raised an issue as you suggested https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/issues/501